# How to install jdk 1.7 to WebSphere 8.5.0.0 (on IBM RAD) from IBM install management (IIM)?

Tags: java, installation, websphere, java-7

I stuck here, we are using a licensed `IBM Rational Application Developer V8.5` which contain `WebSphere 8.5.0.0` as default to develop. As an old project which running on WebSphere need to update and including `jdk` update from `1.6` to `1.7`, the problem is `WebSphere 8.5.0.0` only has `jdk 1.6` as runtime version (As picture below, `JVM 1.6_64`), as showing in second picture, which means I don't have `jdk 7` specific for RAD Websphere on my workspace. And I am not able to find downloading resource now.

[image]
[image]

Try to resolve problem, I refer to two sites below: From link 1, I know I should go to link 2.

1.[WebSphere Application Server JVM version shows as 1.6 for server configured with JRE 1.7 runtime in Rational Application Developer](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21671938)

2.[Installing IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition Version 7.0 or 7.1 using the GUI](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.express.doc/ae/tins_installation_jdk7_gui.html)

In link 2, actually, **NOT** a step by step tutorial and **NO** picture as instruction to show how to install `jdk 7.0` from IBM Install Manager. Also, as mentioned, as we are using RAD, the jdk could not be open source version from Oracle official site, should be specific version (e.g `IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition Version 7.0.4.1`) from IBM official site or repository, that's why I think using IBM Install Manager to finish this install is better.

**Note:** If higher version like `jdk 7.1` or even higher works against WebSphere 8.5.0.0 is also fine, the final target is update to at least `jdk 7.0`

I have Install Manager as below, but as no step by step tutorial, I stuck here.

[image]

Could someone show me how to do this step by step ? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the 2nd link that you mentioned, which is similar to [this](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/ae/tins_installation_jdk7_gui.html), you can use Installation Manager to install WebSphere Java SDK 7 over the internet using this repository:

```
    http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/com.ibm.websphere.IBMJAVA.v70
```

1. Start Installation Manager (GUI)
2. Specify the above repository under **File** > **Preferences** of Installation Manager (and use your IBM ID to authenticate)
3. Click **Install**
4. Select **IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition Version 7.0**
5. Follow the wizard to complete the installation

The procedure is captured in the documentation referenced.

You will want to consider updating to the latest WAS 8.5.5.x fix pack.  8.5.0.0 is the initial release and is a relatively old level.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes, like you said, i open Install Manager and choice first option as `Repositories` setting, but after click `Add repository` the link you write here (this link same to the link on official page, i suppose it is right), the problem is error as "Failed to connect repository", is this related to my RAD Websphere is 8.5.0.0 not 8.5.5.0 (you suggested) or this repository is already decommissioned ?

Comment: No, the failure to connect to repository should not caused by using 8.5.0.0 instead of 8.5.5.0.  Look at the support page https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21286846 for resolving common issues related to repository connections.

Comment: @AnuShibinJosephRaj: You can find the online repositories for WAS V8.5.5 here:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/ae/cins_repositories.html

Comment: You can run ./IBMIM (from under the eclipse folder where you installed Installation Manager) to launch the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you have succesfully installed the JDK you want, you need to investigate the `managesdk` command described on the [managesdk Knowledge Center page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_managesdk.html).  This is the command you use to determine which JDK a profile uses.

Below is a sample session I ran a few years ago.

`C:\ibm\was85\bin>managesdk -listAvailable
CWSDK1003I: Available SDKs :
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.6_64
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.7_64`

`CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.`

`C:\ibm\was85\bin>managesdk -setNewProfileDefault -sdkName 1.7_64
CWSDK1022I: New profile creation will now use SDK name 1.7_64.`


`CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.`

The RAD preferences you reference above determines how your IDE will compile your source code during development.

Comment: hi, thank you for post, but problem is i didn't successfully install the JDK i want, since i install RAD which including `websphere 8.5.0.0`, it default only contain `java 1.6`, not `java 1.7` i want, so the problem first is i need to get the right version of `jdk 7.0` or higher version that can work with RAD, but i searched website, not clear on this part, like where to get IBM jdk, and how to use install manager to install it, thanks

Comment: And also, if i get resource like SDK 1.7_64 or something else, is using the command way you provide here can instead of using IBM Install Management GUI ?

Comment: No, the managesdk command is used to select the version and bitness of JDK used by WebSphere, it is not used to install it.  You want to follow the steps posted above by ykchang.