# RAD8.5.5.0 and WAS 8.5.5.0 with JDK 7 or 8

Tags: java, websphere, rad

I need to upgrade my project from WAS 7 to WAS 8.5, along with that want to upgrade java version as well, as present my project support java6 now we want to migrate it to java 8 if not at least to java 7.

But the issue i got is am unable to select 1.6+ in project facets.
i know by default WAS 8.5.5.0 supports java 1.6, how to upgrade it to 1.6+.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the steps listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598722/how-to-install-jdk-1-7-to-websphere-8-5-0-0-on-ibm-rad-from-ibm-install-manage?  I would also recommend utilizing a newer fixpack of 8.5.5 than 8.5.5.0, as stated here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036014 IBM will only provide iFixes for fixpacks released less than two years ago and 8.5.5.0 was released in 2013.

Comment: Thank You Alex. Now i installed fix pack 12 on WAS 8.5.5 and installed SDK 8. now i could see WAS is using java 8 but in RAD 8.5.5. project facets were showing till 1.7 how to set 1.8

Comment: Now Changed java version in org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml to 1.8. Now am able to see 1.8 but it is showing some error "WebSphere Web(Co-existence) 8.5 requires java with version matching expression ""1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7". What is this Websphere web co-existence all about. and how to update it to 1.8

Comment: What version of RAD are you using?  It looks like support for Java 8 in RAD was added in v9.5.0.2: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/267366/when-will-rad-support-java-80-with-was-v8559-for-j.html

Comment: Mine is RAD 8.5.5. please let me know, Is there any fix pack for this too..?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible with RAD 8.5.5 or not.  I would try the managesdk commands listed under "Here is an example of an existing WAS 8.5.5.9 32-bit profile with Java 6.0. 7.0 and 8.0 installed, and a default of Java 6.0 changed to Java 8.0." on this technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21962198.  Don't forget to close and reopen Eclipse after completing those steps.

Comment: Thank You Alex. I will open another for RAD